# w3af plugin development example

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, web-scanners, plugins, python

I'm new to w3af, and I would like to build my own plugin. I have searched on w3af web and googled it for some examples but no luck...

Can anyone give me an example how to start building plugins or where to look?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to IT Security. That's an awfully specific question about a specific piece of software and therefore not a great fit for the site. Try hitting up the github repo for the answers you seek.

Answer (score 2):

Your searches must have missed the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/tree/master/plugins), which is highlighted on w3af.org.

Examples are all there.

Comment: i saw that, those are finished plugins that are used, I need simple example... there used to be a w3af plugin tutorial with hello world examples... thanks a lot for help and for -2 rep :/